# woocommerce custom fields included in product email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to include a custom field in the email that is sent to customers upon purchase. I added a custom field "Phone_number" into the all of the product pages.

I've tried including

```
 <?php
 $orderidno = $order->id;
 $prodmetaa = get_post_meta($orderidno, "Phone_number" , True);
 echo $prodmetaa;
 ?>
```

In the order email template, but haven't had any success. Has anyone done anything like this before or have any Idea how I could accomplish this .

Plugin URL - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hooks/actions/filters to do so. Here is documentation on doing something like you want http://docs.woothemes.com/document/add-a-custom-field-in-an-order-to-the-emails/

```
/**
 * Add the field to order emails
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys');

function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys['How did you hear about us?'] = 'hear_about_us';
    return $keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon the above tutorial and now taking advantage of the improved email template hooks that I added and I think were released in WC 2.3.0

```
function so_229971110_add_meta_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ){
   $prodmetaa = get_post_meta($order->id, "Phone_number" , True);
   echo "Phone Number: " . $prodmetaa;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'so_229971110_add_meta_to_email', 20, 3 );
```